# syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I'm implementing OmniAuth for LinkedIn on my sign in page, but I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError  
/app/models/user.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

The code it's looking at is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation  
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /([\w+.]+)@[a-z0-9\-.]+\.[a-z]+/i   
  validates :email, presence: true,   
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },   
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }  
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }  
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true  
  devise :rememberable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:linkedin], :trackable
end
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reordering

```
devise :rememberable, :omniauthable, :trackable, :omniauth_providers => [:linkedin]
```

Comment: **Supplementation**: Braces around the hash can only be omitted when the hash is the last argument.

Comment: it now says it can't load OmniAuth, but I guess that's a separate problem.  Thanks for helping me with this one though.